# How to build additional caffe tools?

Tags: makefile, build, cmake, linker, caffe

Under tools folder caffe library have some tools as single .cpp files 
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/tools

I have added my own tool under this folder and can build it via cmake.

The problem that when I have added additional dependency (json lib [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)) build fails at linking phase.

I have put json lib `.h`, `.cpp` files under `tools/json` folder.

My includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "caffe/caffe.hpp"
#include "json/json.h"
```

Error that I get, like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Json::StyledWriter::write(Json::Value const&)", referenced from:
      image_list_processing(int, char**) in my_tool.cpp.o
```

So the question is how to add lib to linking process? Should I modify https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/tools/CMakeLists.txt or maybe I should add separate file under `tools/json/CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error of missing `.h` file. You need to link your code to the shared object (`libjsoncpp.so` of similar) for your code to access (link) compiled json functions.

add `-L /path/to/libjson_folder` and `-ljsoncpp` flags to the **linking** stage of your makefile.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem, but I'm not see that libs are explicitly added in Makefile. Maybe it's here https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile#L436 ? Also here https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile.config.example#L98 is only dirs are specified not the name of the lib.